# Using CRS EPSG:3857 but misalignment between Stamen background and coordinates of polygons in GeoPandas

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, stamen

Using GeoPandas and Contextily to create maps with a Stamen background map I notice a misalignment between the background map and the coordinates of polygons drawn on the map. The shapefile is from the official Dutch Bureau of Statistics so the coordinates are correct.

What can I do?

My usage should be inline with [the instruction](http://geopandas.org/gallery/plotting_basemap_background.html) and the [example notebook](https://github.com/darribas/contextily/blob/master/contextily_guide.ipynb). Others seem to have the same problem, e.g. [this tutorial](https://ricardopasquini.com/mapping-with-geopandas-and-basemapping-with-contextily/).

My original projection is:

```
{'proj': 'sterea',
 'lat_0': 52.15616055555555,
 'lon_0': 5.38763888888889,
 'k': 0.9999079,
 'x_0': 155000,
 'y_0': 463000,
 'ellps': 'bessel',
 'units': 'm',
 'no_defs': True}
```

I perform:

```
dfmap = dfmap.to_crs(epsg=3857)
```

The crs becomes:

```
{'init': 'epsg:3857', 'no_defs': True}
```

I then perform:

```
ax = df.plot(figsize=(10, 10), alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
ctx.add_basemap(ax)
```

But the basemap and polygon are misaligned, as per the map image (the polygon should be more to the left and a bit lower so that the curve aligns with the water on the map):

[image: example of misaligned map]

I tried different zoomlevels, checking axis values, setting `ax.axis('square')`,...

On axis values, adding the basemap changes the values:

```
print(ax.axis())
ctx.add_basemap(ax, zoom=15)
print(ax.axis())
```

Returns:

```
(542505.2085419805, 543235.6744236776, 6866130.598686902, 6866937.041798945)
(541785.6564853293, 544231.6413904548, 6865879.628687669, 6867102.621140235)
```

Which I would not expect considering the following in `add_basemap(ax`)?:

```
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = ax.axis()
# restore original x/y limits
ax.axis((xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))
```

I also tried to add the basemap after performing `dfmap.to_crs(epsg=4326)` but then I get the sea as background. And I also tried with `ll=True` as well as `ll=False` in the `ctx.bounds2img` function:

```
def add_basemap(ax, zoom, url='http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/tileZ/tileX/tileY.png'):
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = ax.axis()
    basemap, extent = ctx.bounds2img(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, zoom=zoom, url=url, ll=True)
    ax.imshow(basemap, extent=extent, interpolation='bilinear')
    # restore original x/y limits
    ax.axis((xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))
```

I lack the knowledge about long lat vs xy but if I read about how "the Web Mercator uses the spherical formulas at all scales whereas large-scale Mercator maps normally use the ellipsoidal form of the projection. The discrepancy is imperceptible at the global scale but causes maps of local areas to deviate slightly from true ellipsoidal Mercator maps at the same scale. This deviation becomes more pronounced further from the equator, and can reach as much as 40 km on the ground." then I guess it relates to that.

But how?

Comment: thanks for the detailed question. I don't directly see something wrong, and normally this should work (Web Mercator should not give such an error at that scale). Would you be able to provide a small sample dataset (to create `dfmap` to try to reproduce the issue) ?

Comment: Thank you so much! I put the sample information in this online folder: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlNIYisf3zAHs8cBi7cUPP-JS9Yl3Q?e=Iqe5HP

Comment: Looks like a datum transformation issue (or lack thereof). 4326 and 3857 use WGS84 as a GCS. You need to transform the Bessel to that for (closer) alignment.

Comment: Thanks. So I cannot use the GeoPandas method .to_crs() in this case and need to do the re-projecting from Bessel to EPSG 3857 in an alternative manner? I will investigate how to do that and get back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause seems to be an incorrect (or incomplete) definition of the CRS of your data. Your data is actually using EPSG:28992 (https://epsg.io/28992), and if you look at the PROJ.4 definition on that webpage is not fully matching the crs that is returned by the original `dfmap.crs` (it is missing the "towgs84" part).

When "correcting" that by overwriting the `crs` attribute with the PROJ.4 string from https://epsg.io/28992, I get the expected result:

```py
dfmap.crs = "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs"
dfmap2 = dfmap.to_crs(epsg=3857)

ax = dfmap2.plot(figsize=(10, 10), alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
contextily.add_basemap(ax)
ax.set_axis_off()
```

[image]

Now, as to *why* this happens for this specific CRS, I don't know. The files you have include a proper WKT description of the CRS in the `.prj` file of the Shapefile.

Comment: Also the map from my question is now perfectly aligned, fantastic, many thanks!

Comment: Update: with the development version of geopandas (to become 0.7), it is working correctly out of the box. The main difference is that we are now requiring a more recent version of pyproj, and when reading the .prj information from the file better preserve the information of the CRS (no longer rely on a roundtrip through PROJ4 strings)